# How can I select another tab instead of current selection tab or cancel select tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

jQuery UI Tabs 1.8.18

```
form.find("#ctrlTabs").tabs({
     select: function (event, ui) {

        if (ui.index == 2) {
             $('#ctrlTabs').tabs("select", 0); - don't work.............
         }
     },
    });
```

When I select Tab with index 2, the question will appear. 
If the question will be not correct I Need select tab with index 0, tab with index 2 do not be shown.

How can I solve this problem?

Or How Can I cancel select tab inside of select event function... ?

Answer (score 0):

Easily

return false;

The problem solved